# How to configure k3s through Rancher Desktop

Tags: configuration, k3s, rancher-desktop

I have a dedicated server running `Ubuntu` and `Rancher Desktop`.

I'd like to be able to access the Kubernetes cluster (K3S) from another computer in the same network.
In doing so, after I've setup my kube configuration, I'm getting an error.

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.43.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.5.15, ::1, fec0::5055:55ff:fe8e:47db, not 192.168.1.8

Passing the following config through to K3S should solve my problem

> INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--tls-san 192.168.1.8"

Reading through Rancher Desktop documentation, I found a potential solution.
Based on the documentation I should be able to pass config through to k3s via the [Provisional Script](https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/provisioning-scripts) for Rancher Desktop. It is still unclear to me as how I do this for the K3S configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The k3s repository has this issue with a proposed solution at https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/3369

"SANs should be added to the dynamiclistener cert on demand, based on the SNI hostname requested by the client. Try running the following on the server:"

```
curl -vk --resolve 172.31.13.97:6443:127.0.0.1  https://172.31.13.97:6443/ping
```